# Will pyodbc automatically connect to the db if default server name is given in a function definition?

Tags: python, python-import, software-design

In a module I have the following function:

```
import pyodbc
def connect_db(server={default_server_name}):
config = {
     'DRIVER': '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
     'TRUSTED_CONNECTION':'Yes'
     'SERVER':server
}

conn = pyodbc.connect(**config)
return conn
```

My question: when I import this module will pyodbc actually connect to the server since a default server name is given? I wouldn't think so, but I ran into a situation where I couldn't import the module (got a pyodbc error) if I wasn't on the internal network, which would indicate that it was trying to connect to the db when imported.

Comment: `server={default_server_name}` looks like incorrect syntax

Comment: I actually use the real server name, just put a placeholder in as "{default_server_name}" so as not to put the real server name.

Comment: ok. but yea i'm pretty sure the `pyodbc.connect` function actively connects you to whatever db you have defined.

Comment: @SuperStew Yeah I was wondering if it would automatically happen even if I only imported the module and didn't actually run the function.

Comment: no just `import pyodbc` shouldn't connect to anything